# What's everything I should replace/maintain while changing the clutch?

Tags: clutch, maintenance, corolla

I've got a 2007 Corolla with what seems to be a bad pilot bearing. I know changing the clutch isn't a trivial job, so I'm going to do whatever else I can do w/ the gearbox removed. I just ordered [this](https://www.rockauto.com/en/moreinfo.php?pk=10340316&cc=1434445&jsn=1826) which contains more than just the clutch kit.

What else is prudent to replace/maintain?

Comment: I could swear I've answered this question, but I can't readily find it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Ah! [Here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/79753/what-else-should-i-check-and-or-repair-when-replacing-the-clutch). Funny, it didn't pop up in the related questions when I looked.